Python - Pandas - In a dataframe row, find the column index of the first occurrence of a value among multiple columns
I'm a beginner at Python.  I’ve been trying all sorts of machinations on this issue and all have failed.  I'm thinking along the lines of how SAS works not used to Python.
What I’m trying to do is find the column index of the first new vehicle, assuming the vehicles in the table are ordered from newest to oldest, and use that to pick other columns with the first new namelate, the first new purchase date, etc.
Here’s what I’m trying to do in SAS pseudo code.
SAS has user defined temporary arrays.  I can make an array like so:
Array newused              newused_status1 – newused_status5
Array nameplate            car1 – car5
And then use the array in a loop.
Do over newused(i)
Find and assign to a variable the index of first vehicle purchased new from array newused
End loop
First new nameplate = nameplate(index of first new vehicle)

I could not find very similar methods in python.
What I tried to do was look for the first occurrence of NEW among newused_status1 – newused_status 5, do some text processing to substring the number associated with the first new vehicle and make a new value – nameplate#of first newused, - nameplate1 or nameplate2, whichever is the first new vehicle.
What I couldn’t make happen is to use the column name value to make an assignment;  first_new_nameplate = mydataframe[nameplate#of first newused]
Here is my beginners python code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([[12345,"Name1","Name1","Name2","","","A","U","N","N","",""], 
               [45678,"Name3","Name1","Name2","","","S","N","N","N","",""],
               [45679,"Name2","Name2","Name2","","","S","U","U","U","",""],
               [98765,"Name3","Name2","Name2","","","","CPO","U","N","",""]], 
           columns=("ID","Car1","Car2","Car3","Car4","Car5","Income",
                    "NU1","NU2","NU3","NU4","NU5") )

nu_array = df[["NU1","NU2","NU3","NU4","NU5"]] 
nameplate_array = df[["Car1","Car2","Car3","Car4","Car5"]] 



#find name of first new vehicle column – create a new column – value in the new column is the     name of the column with the first new car name

df['first_nu_col_name'] = df.eq("N").T.idxmax()  
**# ONE PROBLEM HERE - this returns a column name even for row 3 where all vehicles are "U" (used)**

df['col_num'] = df['first_nu_col_name'].str[2:]
df['first_nu_veh_col_name'] = "Car" + df['col_num']

#My code does return the correct column name, except where there is no new vehicle - then it returns a name that is incorrect
#I tried iterating and failed (i.e. using a loop as I described in the SAS pseudo code)  From what I’m reading iterating in a loop is not ‘pythonic’ and vectoring is much better, however
#I haven’t run across anything from googling that has worked and nothing (I could understand) regarding a vector solution

What I need to do:

Correct returning a value for a new vehicle when no vehicle in the row is new
Create new variables by applying the location of the first new vehicle to other descriptors arranged in the same way (i.e. purchase_date1-5, price1-5, etc.) - either as an index or a column name

I tried to apply a column index or name of interest in each row in a dataframe to find the value I wanted among other columns - the result was error messages.  Using functions like index() or trying to use the first_nu_veh_col_name as a column name did not work.

When you have no True in a row, idxmax will return the index of the first False.
A vectorial approach to avoid this would be to combine idxmax with where and any to get a NaN when there was no True in a row:
m = df.eq('N')
df['first_nu_col_name'] = m.idxmax(axis=1).where(m.any(axis=1))
df['col_num'] = df['first_nu_col_name'].str[2:]
df['first_nu_veh_col_name'] = "Car" + df['col_num']

One-liner variant (python ≥ 3.8):
df['first_nu_col_name'] = (m:=df.eq('N')).idxmax(axis=1).where(m.any(axis=1))

Output:
      ID   Car1   Car2   Car3 Car4 Car5 Income  NU1 NU2 NU3 NU4 NU5 first_nu_col_name col_num first_nu_veh_col_name
0  12345  Name1  Name1  Name2                A    U   N   N                       NU2       2                  Car2
1  45678  Name3  Name1  Name2                S    N   N   N                       NU1       1                  Car1
2  45679  Name2  Name2  Name2                S    U   U   U                       NaN     NaN                   NaN
3  98765  Name3  Name2  Name2                   CPO   U   N                       NU3       3                  Car3

Intermediates:
# m
      ID   Car1   Car2   Car3   Car4   Car5  Income    NU1    NU2    NU3  \
0  False  False  False  False  False  False   False  False   True   True   
1  False  False  False  False  False  False   False   True   True   True   
2  False  False  False  False  False  False   False  False  False  False   
3  False  False  False  False  False  False   False  False  False   True   

     NU4    NU5  first_nu_col_name  col_num  first_nu_veh_col_name  
0  False  False              False    False                  False  
1  False  False              False    False                  False  
2  False  False              False    False                  False  
3  False  False              False    False                  False  

# m.idxmax(axis=1)
0    NU2
1    NU1
2     ID
3    NU3
dtype: object

# m.any(axis=1)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

# m.idxmax(axis=1).where(m.any(axis=1))
0    NU2
1    NU1
2    NaN
3    NU3
dtype: object

Side note
You are running idxmax on all the columns, if you want to restrict to the NU columns, use filter:
m = df.filter(like='NU').eq('N')

     NU1    NU2    NU3    NU4    NU5
0  False   True   True  False  False
1   True   True   True  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False   True  False  False


Thanks, I used this on another part of my program.

First we find the index of the first new vehicle, if there is not one, it returns None :
df['first_new_index'] = nu_array.apply(lambda row: next((i+1 for i, val in enumerate(row) 
                                                        if val == 'N'), 
                                                       None), 
                                      axis=1)

Then we find the nameplate of the first new car, returning None if there is no numeric value.
df['first_new_nameplate'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[f'Car{int(row["first_new_index"])}'] 
                                                 if pd.notnull(row["first_new_index"]) 
                                                 else None, 
                                     axis=1)



This is perfect for my use, thanks.

Use idxmax(), but then use iterate through the series to check if the max is 'N'.
max_nu = (df[['NU1', 'NU2', 'NU3', 'NU4', 'NU5']] == 'N').idxmax(axis = 'columns')
df['first_nu_veh_col_name'] = ''

for index, col in max_nu.items():
    if df.loc[index, col] == 'N':
        df.loc[index, 'first_nu_veh_col_name'] = 'Car' + col[2:]

